# Quelle est l'origine de l'expression « brûler le dur » ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

Je comprends que ça veut dire *prendre un train sans payer*, mais quelle est l'origine ? *le dur*, qu'est-ce que c'est en ce cas ? Pourquoi brûler ?

Comment: Je ne l'avais jamais entendue. Sais-tu où elle est employée ? Plus difficile en tout cas à deviner qu'un *resto-basket* :-)

Comment: Bonjours, @RomainVALERI :). Oui, voici une référence trouvée dans un romain par Alain Tercinet. Page 28 (premier alinéa au-dessous Cherokee) - http://books.google.fr/books?id=06Swmo63YHkC&pg=PA28&dq=%22br%C3%BBle+le+dur%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xQQGUOLIMq2yiQfX_pm0CA&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22br%C3%BBle%20le%20dur%22&f=false

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Selon le *dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) :

> *Brûler* au sens figuré, par référence à la rapidité du feu, à partir du 18ème siècle exprime l'idée de « passer sans s'arrêter à un point prévu », aujourd'hui encore fréquent dans « brûler un feu rouge », « brûler les étapes ». De là, en argot ancien, le sens de laisser impayé
>   apparu avant 1789.

Selon le *dictionnaire Culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey) :

> Dur : (1886, au sens de « fer » 1836) Argot, puis familier : train. 
>   *Prendre le dur*. *Brûler le dur* : voyager en fraude par le train. « Il prit son billet en vitesse et son dur juste à temps [...] »
>   (Queneau, le dimanche de la vie).

Answer (score 7):

C'est un argot qui semble très vieilli dont on trouve [référence](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire%3aR%C3%A9f%C3%A9rences#Dictionnaire_Argot-Fran.C3.A7ais) dans [le dictionnaire Argot-Francais de N.Hayard](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/18024/18024-h/18024-h.htm) et repris sans trop d'explications [ici](http://russki-mat.net/find.php?l=FrFr&q=br%C3%BBler&c=lem) ou [là](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=2738).
Même dans le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/br%C3%BBler_le_dur), le paragraphe étymologie laisse sur sa faim.

Le seul embryon d'explication que j'ai trouvé vient de [Monsieur Dico](http://www.lalibre.be/archives/divers/article/173823/monsieur-dico.html):

> *En argot, on utilisait «brûler» pour «laisser impayé». Si on brûlait le bateau, c'est qu'on ne réglait pas le prix de la traversée. Francis Guillot l'explique dans «Le p'tit Francis» : «Dans mon portefeuille, j'avais la lettre d'un copain. Il m'écrivait qu'il était en taule à Bordeaux pour trois mois parce qu'il avait «brûlé le bateau en rentrant du Venezuela»». «Brûler le bateau», en argot, ça veut dire faire le trajet clandestinement, sans payer, comme on dit pour les trains: «brûler le dur». Mais en y réfléchissant, dans un même sens métaphorique on trouve «brûler la politesse», s'enfuir, «brûler sa santé», l'user prématurément...*

Mais ça n'explique pas *dur*.
Est-ce parce que *chemin de fer* et *dur comme fer*?

C'est aussi bien sur la traduction du titre anglais de la nouvelle *Holding Her Down* dans *The Road* de Jack London.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: Merci pour les corrections...

Answer (score 2):

Le *dur* date du temps des trains à vapeur et des troisièmes classes qui proposaient les tarifs les plus bas : les sièges inconfortables y étaient en bois sans aucun rembourrage, au contraires des autres classes, d'où l'expression :

> Voyager à la dure

*Brûler le dur* :

- Prendre le train sans avoir assez d'argent pour se payer un voyage en troisième classe,
- Comportement coutumier d'un voyou pour voyager sans payer.